# Performing volume calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, qgis-processing, error

EDIT 07/12/12

I came to another problem I want to discuss.
I just tried around with the volume calculation with some layers and came to a point where I receive the following error.
Screenshot:

[image: error]

I did some research and discovered this explanation:
http://blog.webforefront.com/archives/2011/02/python_ascii_co.html
The problem is, that I have absolutely no Idea about python programming.

Does anyone know how to solve this described error problem?

Note: I left the older questions below in order to see the process I made.

---

---

---

I m currently trying to make a volume calculation in QGIS. I realised, that
using GRASS or Sextante is the right choice to do this. But since there are barely useful tutorials, that go into depht nor any other guides or hints that may help in this context, I want to seek help here.
So I want to ask these questions:

1)I want to calculate the volume of a specific map area. So I discovered the algorithm "r.volume."

1.1.)How does it work exactly?  The Help text in that menu is not very useful for me as a Grass beginner.

1.2) Why do I need raster layers for this and no vector layers?

1.3) What certain criteria do these rasters have to fulfill?

1.4) I added a screenshot. What exactly are these "clumps" and what rasters have to be chosen in the drop down list?

1.5) Can I have an accurate example of how to perform such an r.volume algorithm?

2)I learned, that GRASS (in QGIS) was integrated into the Sextante Plugin for QGIS.

2.1) Does this mean I can only use Sextante and still have all the functions of Grassgis? I would welcome that because I always had trouble with importing data into Grassgis. Sextante doesn t (obiously) require this.(?)

2.2) A strengh of **gvSIG** is Sextante, so I read; Is the Sextante Plugin for QGIS equal to gvSIG Sextante concerning performance/ possibilities?

---

EDIT:07/11/12 8.08am:

I know this is not easy to answer but it would be great too, if you can help me out with the other questions (2.1/2.2).

---

[image: r.volume menue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update;
I tried the volume calculation again and came to the conclusion that it can be done with **grass**, since sextante produces this weird error (see above).
Set the Mapset and convert your raster layer(it has to be a file that countains the elevation data(dem)) to a grass file. Make sure, all projections match, otherwise an error will occur during conversion.
First run **r.clump**, that will produce another raster(clump-map).Convert this one into grass too.
In **r.volume** you ll now use your both rasters and run the method. Worked good for me.

Answer (score 2):

UnicodeDecodeErrors can be cryptic, but I think you're fortunate in having a situation that's easy to debug. Look at the statement

```
text = unicode(a)
```

The unicode function uses the ascii codec by default, so that is equivalent to

```
text = unicode(a, 'ascii')
```

Check to see whether the value of a in your case is not an ascii encoded string. Is it UTF-8 or some other? If it is, you'll need to pass the proper encoding to the unicode method. Here's an example of what would happen if your data was a UTF-8 encoded string and you didn't account for that:

```
>>> a = "Σταυρόπολις"
>>> a
'\xce\xa3\xcf\x84\xce\xb1\xcf\x85\xcf\x81\xe1\xbd\xb9\xcf\x80\xce\xbf\xce\xbb\xce\xb9\xcf\x82'
>>> unicode(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode(a, 'utf-8')
u'\u03a3\u03c4\u03b1\u03c5\u03c1\u1f79\u03c0\u03bf\u03bb\u03b9\u03c2'
```

The Sextante plugin code needs to get the proper encoding for your data instead of assuming it's ascii.